# Mobile friendly Styling for Esri Widgets in JavaScript 4.x API and Calcite

Tags: routing, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, widget, mobile-gis, coding-style

Has anyone had difficulty (or experience) styling Esri widgets for mobile friendly use?

I am currently working on a routing application whose code structure (I believe) makes it impossible to access the various objects to style using CSS. I am hoping to separate all of the elements nested within the sidebar and put them into a menu dropdown format on the top of a cell/tablet screen. I'm not sure if this is default behavior because they are Esri widgets, or if it is due to the structure of the HTML.

**HTML:**

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- General HTML Info -->
    <title>Campus Map</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent" />
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#332c2c">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />

    <!-- Import the JavaScript 4.x API and Calcite -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.13/esri/themes/dark/main.css">
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.13/"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://esri.github.io/calcite-maps/dist/css/calcite-maps-arcgis-4.x.min-v0.8.css" />

    <!-- Import Local Files -->
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    
    <!-- gives functionality to new information button and menu kae -->
    <script>
      // When the user clicks on the button toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content 
      function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
      }

      // Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
      window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
          var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
          var i;
          for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
              if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
              }
            }
          }
        }
    </script>
    <!-- STYLE SPLASH KAE -->
    <style> 
    .overlay {
      position:fixed;
      top:-999em;
      left:-999em;
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
      z-index:99;
      display:table;
      background: #000000;
      -webkit-animation: splash 5s forwards; 
      animation: splash 5s forwards;
    }
    
    .overlay-inner {
      display:table-cell;
      vertical-align:middle;
      text-align:center;
    }
    
    #VandyStar {
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-top: -8%;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes splash {
      0%  {opacity: 1;top:0;left:0}
      20% {opacity:1;top:0;left:0}
      60% {opacity:1;top:0;left:0}
      99% {top:0;left:0}
      100% {opacity:0;top:-999em;left:-999em}
    }
    @-moz-keyframes splash {
      0%  {opacity: 1;top:0;left:0}
      20% {opacity:1;top:0;left:0}
      60% {opacity:1;top:0;left:0}
      99% {top:0;left:0}
      100% {opacity:0;top:-999em;left:-999em}
    }
    @-ms-keyframes splash {
      0%   {opacity: 1;top:0;left:0}
         20% {opacity:1;top:0;left:0}
         60% {opacity:1;top:0;left:0}
         99% {top:0;left:0}
         100% {opacity:0;top:-999em;left:-999em}
    }  
    @keyframes splash {
      0%  {opacity: 1;top:0;left:0}
      20% {opacity:1;top:0;left:0}
      60% {opacity:1;top:0;left:0}
      99% {top:0;left:0}
      100% {opacity:0;top:-999em;left:-999em}
    }
    
    .loader {
      border: 4px solid #000000;
      border-radius: 50%;
      border-top: 4px solid rgb(168,153,110);
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-top: -8.5%;
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite; /* Safari */
      animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    }

    /* Safari */
    @-webkit-keyframes spin {
      0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
      100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
    }

    @keyframes spin {
      0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
      100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
    }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" data-dojo-attach-point="map">
      <div id="sidebar" data-dojo-attach-point="sidebar" class="esri-widget">
        <div id="sidebarHeading">
          <div id="layerInfoView" data-dojo-attach-point="layerInfoView">
            <div id="searchContainer" class="esri-widget" >
              <div id="searchWidgetDiv"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="layerContainer" class="esri-widget">
              <div id="layerContainerName" class="sidebarContainerName">Layers</div>
              <div id="layerWidgetDiv" data-dojo-attach-point="layerWidgetDiv"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="legendContainer" class="esri-widget">
              <div id="legendContainerName" class="sidebarContainerName">Legend</div>
              <div id="legendWidgetDiv"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="routingView" data-dojo-attach-point="routingView">
            <div id="directionsWidgetContainer" data-dojo-attach-point="directionsWidgetContainer"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="tabsContainer" data-dojo-attach-point="tabsContainer">
        <!-- NEW TOOLTIP TEXT KAE -->
        <div class="tooltip" title="Features">
          <div id="layerInfoDisplayDiv" data-dojo-attach-point="layerInfoDisplayDiv" class="displayButtonDivs">
            <a><div class="displayButton esri-icon-drag-horizontal"></div></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tooltip" title="Directions">
          <div id="routingDisplayDiv" data-dojo-attach-point="routingDisplayDiv" class="displayButtonDivs">
            <a><div class="displayButton esri-icon-directions"></div></a>
          </div> 
        </div>
        <!-- END OF NEW TOOLTIP TEXT KAE --> 
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- NEW INFORMATION BUTTON AND MENU KAE -->
    <div class="dropup" title="Instructions & Policies">
      <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">?</button>
        <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
           <a href="InfoPages/MapInstructions.html" target="_blank">Map Instructions</a>
           <a href="InfoPages/BuildingDirectory.html" target="_blank">Building Directory</a>
           <a href="InfoPages/Feedback.html" target="_blank">Feedback</a>
           <a href="InfoPages/About.html" target="_blank">About</a>
           <a href="InfoPages/MoveInParkingApp.html" target="_blank">Move-in Parking App</a>
           <a href="InfoPages/GraduationParkingApp.html" target="_blank">Graduation Parking App</a>
           <a href="InfoPages/SitePolicies.html" target="_blank">Site Policies</a>
           <a href="InfoPages/Changelog.html" target="_blank">Changelog</a>  
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay">
    <div class="overlay-inner">
        <div class="loader"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- end of new information button and menu kae -->
  </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```js
require([
  "dojo/_base/array",
  "dojo/_base/lang",
  "dojo/dom",
  "dojo/dom-class",
  "dojo/dom-construct",
  "dojo/dom-style",
  "dojo/on",
  "dojo/aspect",
  "dojo/text!./config.json",
  
  "dijit/Tooltip",

  "esri/Map",
  "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
  "esri/tasks/QueryTask",
  "esri/tasks/Locator",
  "esri/tasks/support/DataFile",
  "esri/tasks/support/DataLayer",
  "esri/tasks/support/FeatureSet",
  "esri/tasks/support/Query",
  "esri/tasks/support/RouteParameters",
  "esri/views/MapView",
  "esri/WebMap",

  "esri/widgets/Directions",
  "esri/widgets/Directions/DirectionsViewModel",
  "esri/widgets/Home",
  "esri/widgets/LayerList",
  "esri/widgets/Legend",
  "esri/widgets/Search",
  "esri/widgets/Compass", //allow new compass kae
  "esri/widgets/Track" //allow device tracking kae
], function(array, lang, dom, domClass, domConstruct, domStyle, on, aspect, configFile, Tooltip,
            Map, FeatureLayer, QueryTask, Locator, DataFile, DataLayer, FeatureSet, Query, 
            RouteParameters, MapView, WebMap, Directions, DirectionsVM, Home, LayerList, Legend, 
            Search, Compass, Track) {

    var config = JSON.parse(configFile);
    var directionsViewModel = null;
    var directionsStartSearch, directionsEndSearch, alreadyRanPostRenderStops;
    this.activeDisplay = "layerInfo";
    var routingHasBeenClicked = false;
    var accessibleRoutingEnabled = false;
    var directionsWidget = null;
    var accessibilityObstacles = {};

    //new tooltip({connectid: ["layerinfodisplaydiv"], label: "layer list"});   doesn't really do anything kae
    //new Tooltip({connectId: ["routingDisplayDiv"], label: "Directions"});     doesn't really do anything kae

    //create the layers for processing and map's application
    var webmap = new WebMap({
        portalItem: {
          id: config.webmap
        }
    });
    
    var map = new Map({
        basemap: "topo"
    });
    
    var view = new MapView({
        container: "map",
        map: webmap,
        padding: 300
    });
    
    var compass = new Compass({ //new compass kae
        view: view
    });
    
    var trackWidget = new Track({ //new tracking widget kae
        view: view
    });
    
    var buildingsLayer = new FeatureLayer({
        url: config.buildingsLayerUrl,
        outFields: ["*"]
    });
    
    var parkingLayer = new FeatureLayer({
        url: config.parkingLotsLayerUrl,
        outFields: ["*"]
    });
    
    var routingLayer = new FeatureLayer({
        url: config.routeServicePoints,
        outFields: config.routePointFields
    });

    //add the home button
    var homeWidget = new Home({
        view: view
    });
    
    view.ui.add(homeWidget, {
        position: "top-left"
    });
  
    //add tracking widget kae
    view.ui.add(trackWidget, "top-left");

    //add new compass kae
    view.ui.add(compass, "top-left");

    //create the search bar
    var searchWidget = new Search({
    view: view,
    container: "searchWidgetDiv",
    searchAllEnabled: true,
    suggestionsEnabled: true,
    includeDefaultSources: false, 
    minSuggestCharacters: 0,
    maxResults: 5,
    allPlaceholder: "Search for Buildings or Parking",
    sources: [
      {
        layer: buildingsLayer,
        suggestionsEnabled: true,
        searchFields: ["LONGNAME"],
        displayField: "LONGNAME",
        exactMatch: false,
        outFields: ["LONGNAME"],
        name: "Buildings",
        placeholder: "Search for Buildings"
      },
      {
        layer: parkingLayer,
        suggestionsEnabled: true,
        searchFields: ["FACILITYID"],
        displayField: "FACILITYID",
        exactMatch: false,
        outFields: ["FACILITYID"],
        name: "Parking Lots",
        placeholder: "Search for Parking Lots"
      },
    ]
    });

    //create the layer list - users should not be able to toggle buildings and parking lots
    var layerListWidget = new LayerList({
    view: view,
    container: this.layerWidgetDiv,
    statusIndicatorsVisible: false,
    listItemCreatedFunction: function(event) {
      //check to see if the layer is one that the user is not supposed to be able to toggle on / off
      if(config.nonToggleableLayers.indexOf(event.item.title) > -1){
        if(dom.byId("layerWidgetDiv_" + event.item.uid + "__title")){
          dom.byId("layerWidgetDiv_" + event.item.uid + "__title").parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
    });

    //create the legend
    var legendWidget = new Legend({
    view: view,
    container: "legendWidgetDiv",
    basemapLegendVisible: false
    });

    //get the construction zones
    var constructionQueryTask = new QueryTask({
    url: config.constructionQueryUrl        // moved to config.json hpb 2021016
    });

    var constructionQuery = new Query();
    constructionQuery.returnGeometry = true;
    constructionQuery.where = "1=1";
    constructionQuery.outFields = ["*"];
    constructionQueryTask.execute(constructionQuery).then(lang.hitch(this, function(results) {
        //set up the parameters for determining the routing
        var constructionZones = new FeatureSet({
          features: results.features,
          geometryType: "polygon"
        });
        
        array.forEach(constructionZones.features, lang.hitch(this, function(feature) {
          feature.attributes = null;
        }));
        
        var directionsParameters = new RouteParameters({
          polygonBarriers: constructionZones,
          directionsLengthUnits: "miles",
          directionsOutputType: "complete",
          findBestSequence: false,
          ignoreInvalidLocations: true,
          outputLines: "true-shape",
          preserveFirstStop: true,
          preserveLastStop: true,
          restrictUTurns: "at-dead-ends-and-intersections",
          returnBarriers: false,
          returnDirections: true,
          returnRoutes: false,
          returnStops: true,
          useHierarchy: true,
          useTimeWindows: false
        });
        
        directionsViewModel = new DirectionsVM({
          routeParameters: directionsParameters,
          routeServiceUrl: config.routeServiceUrl,
          view: view
        });
        directionsViewModel.selectedTravelMode = 1;

        //create the directions widget
        directionsWidget = new Directions({
            view: view,
            container: this.directionsWidgetContainer,
            viewModel: directionsViewModel,
            searchProperties: {
                view: view,
                searchAllEnabled: true,
                suggestionsEnabled: true,
                includeDefaultSources: false,
                minSuggestCharacters: 3,
                maxResults: 5,
                sources: [
                    {   
                        locator: new Locator("https://maps.cpc-fis.vanderbilt.edu/arcgis/rest/services/VandyLocator/GeocodeServer"),  
                        suggestionsEnabled: true,
                        searchFields: ["LONGNAME"],
                        displayField: "LONGNAME",
                        exactMatch: false,
                        outFields: ["LONGNAME"],
                        name: "Buildings, Parking Lots, and Lawns",
                        placeholder: "Search for Buildings" 
                    }, 
                    {
                        layer: routingLayer,
                        searchFields: config.routePointFields,
                        displayField: config.routePointFields[0],
                        exactMatch: false,
                        outFields: config.routePointFields,
                        name: "Routing",
                        placeholder: "Search for Location"
                    }
                ]
            }
        });
    }));

    //get the obstacles for the accessibility routes
    var accessibilityQueryTask = new QueryTask({
        url: config.accessibilityQueryUrl       // moved to config.json hpb 2021016
    });

    var accessibilityQuery = new Query();
    accessibilityQuery.returnGeometry = true;
    accessibilityQuery.where = "1=1";
    accessibilityQuery.outFields = ["*"];
    accessibilityQueryTask.execute(accessibilityQuery).then(lang.hitch(this, function(results) {
        accessibilityObstacles = new FeatureSet({
            features: results.features,
            geometryType: "point"
        });
        array.forEach(accessibilityObstacles.features, lang.hitch(this, function(feature){
            feature.attributes = null;
        }));
    }));

    //if the user clicks a display tab that's already selected, hide the sidebar
    _hideSidebar = function(){
        //had to define sidebar, tabsContainer and rewrite function for firefox kae
        var x = document.getElementById("sidebar");
        var y = document.getElementById("tabsContainer");
        if (x.style.display === "none") {
          x.style.display = "block";
          y.style.right = "337px";
        } else {
          x.style.display = "none";
          y.style.right = "0px";
        }
        //this.sidebar.style.display = "none"; KILLS FUNCTIONALITY IN FIREFOX KAE
        //this.tabsContainer.style.right = "0px"; KILLS FUNCTIONALITY IN FIREFOX KAE
        this.activeDisplay = "hidden";
    }

    //if the user clicks a display tab that isn't currently selected, display it
    _updateDisplay = function(newDisplay) {
        //make sure the sidebar is displayed  
        //had to define sidebar and rewrite sidebar styling for firefox kae
        var x = document.getElementById("sidebar");
        this.tabsContainer.style.right = "337px";
        x.style.display = "unset";
        //this.sidebar.style.display = "unset"; kills functionality in firefox kae
        //update the display to the appropriate tab
        if(newDisplay === "routing") {
          this.layerInfoView.style.display = "none";
          this.routingView.style.display = "unset";
        } else {
          this.routingView.style.display = "none";
          this.layerInfoView.style.display = "unset";
        }
        this.activeDisplay = newDisplay;
    }

    //create the functionality for switching the displays
    on(this.layerInfoDisplayDiv, "click", lang.hitch(this, function() {
        if(this.activeDisplay === "layerInfo") {
          _hideSidebar();
        } else {
          _updateDisplay("layerInfo");
        }
    }));

    on(this.routingDisplayDiv, "click", lang.hitch(this, function() {
        //the first time the routing display is clicked, add the 'accessibility options' checkbox to the div
        if(!routingHasBeenClicked) {
          routingHasBeenClicked = true;
          var accessibilityOptionsDiv = domConstruct.create("div", { id: "accessibilityOptionsDiv" }, directionsWidget.domNode.querySelector(".esri-directions__section"));
          accessibilityCheckbox = domConstruct.create("div", { class: "esri-icon-checkbox-unchecked accesibilityCheckbox" }, accessibilityOptionsDiv);
          domConstruct.create("div", { innerHTML: "Accessible Friendly Directions" }, accessibilityOptionsDiv);
          //when the user clicks the checkbox, toggle the accessibility options for routing
          on(accessibilityOptionsDiv, "click", lang.hitch(this, function(){
            domClass.toggle(accessibilityCheckbox, "esri-icon-checkbox-unchecked");
            domClass.toggle(accessibilityCheckbox, "esri-icon-checkbox-checked");
            accessibleRoutingEnabled = !accessibleRoutingEnabled;
            //update the route obstacles
            directionsWidget.viewModel.routeParameters.pointBarriers = accessibleRoutingEnabled ? accessibilityObstacles : null;
            //refresh the route - if there are points input
            var searchInputs = directionsWidget.domNode.querySelectorAll(".esri-search__input");
            var validInputs = true;
            array.forEach(searchInputs, lang.hitch(this, function(searchInput) {
              if(searchInput.value === "") {
                validInputs = false;
              }
            }));
            if(validInputs) {
              directionsViewModel.stops.forEach(lang.hitch(this, function(stop) {
                console.log("stop", stop);
              }));
              directionsWidget.getDirections();
            }
          }));
        }
        if(this.activeDisplay === "routing") {
          _hideSidebar();
        } else {
          _updateDisplay("routing");
        }
    }));
});
```

Comment: I actually reached out to the Calcite team on the mobile topic. Their response was, they're working on some things, but dont have an ETA.  For now, to make use of mediaQueries. In terms of modifying core widgets - I dont have any suggestions, sorry.

Comment: You may have already seen this help topic, but I've used the approach of collapsing whole widgets into a button with some success. https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/view-breakpoints-css/